# D3: load hyperlink dynamically on click

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new to D3 and javascript. I have found a tree layout that suits my needs and now I'm trying to make it display information dynamically. This is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sebarn/ap7t24L9/) for the tree.

Right now, when you click on a node, a hyperlink is displayed on top of the tree. The problem is that this is just a text string and not a clickable hyperlink.

I know that this is related to my code not actually telling D3 to display this as a hyperlink:

```
function click(d) {
  d3.select("#link").text(d.url);
  update(d);
}
```

I've tried to make it work using the [javascript link() method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_str_link), but wasn't very successful (the debugger said: link() method not found). How can I turn the text string into a clickable link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `<a>` tag to the `<div>` displaying your link:

```
<div>
  <a id="#link"></a>
</div>
```

Then, you can update the link tag, like this:

```
d3.select("#link")
  .attr("href", d.url)
  .text(d.url);
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped ;-). When I used your code, the problem was that <a> tags got added and not removed. I've amended the code a bit and now it works (jsfiddle is updated). 

function click(d) {
    d3.select("#link").attr("href",d.url).text(d.url);
  update(d);
}

and 

<div>
    <a id="link"></a>    
</div>

Comment: Yeah, that's even better. I will update the answer with your improvement. Do you mark the answer as correct?